# NoSuchMethodError : The Setter "movies=" was called on null

Tags: api, flutter, dart

```
    Future<YifyMovies> getData() async {
    var res = await http.get("https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json");
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);

    YifyMovies movie = YifyMovies();
    movie.data.movies = [];

    for (var json in decodedJson) {
      movie.data.movies.add(Movies.fromJson(json));
    }

    return movie;
  }
```

Yify Movies class:-

It's the JSON from the above API converted int0 dart.

```
class YifyMovies {
  String status;
  String statusMessage;
  Data data;

  YifyMovies({this.status, this.statusMessage, this.data});

  YifyMovies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    statusMessage = json['status_message'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['status_message'] = this.statusMessage;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int movieCount;
  int limit;
  int pageNumber;
  List<Movies> movies;

  Data({this.movieCount, this.limit, this.pageNumber, this.movies});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    movieCount = json['movie_count'];
    limit = json['limit'];
    pageNumber = json['page_number'];
    if (json['movies'] != null) {
      movies = new List<Movies>();
      json['movies'].forEach((v) {
        movies.add(new Movies.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['movie_count'] = this.movieCount;
    data['limit'] = this.limit;
    data['page_number'] = this.pageNumber;
    if (this.movies != null) {
      data['movies'] = this.movies.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Movies {
  int id;
  String url;
  String imdbCode;
  String title;
  String titleEnglish;
  String titleLong;
  String slug;
  int year;
  double rating;
  int runtime;
  List<String> genres;
  String summary;
  String descriptionFull;
  String synopsis;
  String ytTrailerCode;
  String language;
  String mpaRating;
  String backgroundImage;
  String backgroundImageOriginal;
  String smallCoverImage;
  String mediumCoverImage;
  String largeCoverImage;
  String state;
  List<Torrents> torrents;
  String dateUploaded;
  int dateUploadedUnix;

  Movies(
      {this.id,
      this.url,
      this.imdbCode,
      this.title,
      this.titleEnglish,
      this.titleLong,
      this.slug,
      this.year,
      this.rating,
      this.runtime,
      this.genres,
      this.summary,
      this.descriptionFull,
      this.synopsis,
      this.ytTrailerCode,
      this.language,
      this.mpaRating,
      this.backgroundImage,
      this.backgroundImageOriginal,
      this.smallCoverImage,
      this.mediumCoverImage,
      this.largeCoverImage,
      this.state,
      this.torrents,
      this.dateUploaded,
      this.dateUploadedUnix});

  Movies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    url = json['url'];
    imdbCode = json['imdb_code'];
    title = json['title'];
    titleEnglish = json['title_english'];
    titleLong = json['title_long'];
    slug = json['slug'];
    year = json['year'];
    rating = json['rating'];
    runtime = json['runtime'];
    genres = json['genres'].cast<String>();
    summary = json['summary'];
    descriptionFull = json['description_full'];
    synopsis = json['synopsis'];
    ytTrailerCode = json['yt_trailer_code'];
    language = json['language'];
    mpaRating = json['mpa_rating'];
    backgroundImage = json['background_image'];
    backgroundImageOriginal = json['background_image_original'];
    smallCoverImage = json['small_cover_image'];
    mediumCoverImage = json['medium_cover_image'];
    largeCoverImage = json['large_cover_image'];
    state = json['state'];
    if (json['torrents'] != null) {
      torrents = new List<Torrents>();
      json['torrents'].forEach((v) {
        torrents.add(new Torrents.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    dateUploaded = json['date_uploaded'];
    dateUploadedUnix = json['date_uploaded_unix'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['imdb_code'] = this.imdbCode;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['title_english'] = this.titleEnglish;
    data['title_long'] = this.titleLong;
    data['slug'] = this.slug;
    data['year'] = this.year;
    data['rating'] = this.rating;
    data['runtime'] = this.runtime;
    data['genres'] = this.genres;
    data['summary'] = this.summary;
    data['description_full'] = this.descriptionFull;
    data['synopsis'] = this.synopsis;
    data['yt_trailer_code'] = this.ytTrailerCode;
    data['language'] = this.language;
    data['mpa_rating'] = this.mpaRating;
    data['background_image'] = this.backgroundImage;
    data['background_image_original'] = this.backgroundImageOriginal;
    data['small_cover_image'] = this.smallCoverImage;
    data['medium_cover_image'] = this.mediumCoverImage;
    data['large_cover_image'] = this.largeCoverImage;
    data['state'] = this.state;
    if (this.torrents != null) {
      data['torrents'] = this.torrents.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['date_uploaded'] = this.dateUploaded;
    data['date_uploaded_unix'] = this.dateUploadedUnix;
    return data;
  }
}

class Torrents {
  String url;
  String hash;
  String quality;
  String type;
  int seeds;
  int peers;
  String size;
  int sizeBytes;
  String dateUploaded;
  int dateUploadedUnix;

  Torrents(
      {this.url,
      this.hash,
      this.quality,
      this.type,
      this.seeds,
      this.peers,
      this.size,
      this.sizeBytes,
      this.dateUploaded,
      this.dateUploadedUnix});

  Torrents.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    hash = json['hash'];
    quality = json['quality'];
    type = json['type'];
    seeds = json['seeds'];
    peers = json['peers'];
    size = json['size'];
    sizeBytes = json['size_bytes'];
    dateUploaded = json['date_uploaded'];
    dateUploadedUnix = json['date_uploaded_unix'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['hash'] = this.hash;
    data['quality'] = this.quality;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['seeds'] = this.seeds;
    data['peers'] = this.peers;
    data['size'] = this.size;
    data['size_bytes'] = this.sizeBytes;
    data['date_uploaded'] = this.dateUploaded;
    data['date_uploaded_unix'] = this.dateUploadedUnix;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Any help, please? Tell me if any more info is required?

I'm trying to list all the movies and use them for tabview in flutter which can show them in listview as well as gridview. I'm using Bloc architecture for layouts so YifyMovie class is in hom_model and the code above is in home_provider.

Comment: Can you show what's in the `YifyMovies` class?

Comment: It's the JSON from that API converted to dart.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele I have added the code for YifyMovies class. I'm new to flutter and android development.

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `YifyMovies` class is already handling the parsing for you. 
So your code should change from

```
Future<YifyMovies> getData() async {
    var res = await http.get("https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json");
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);

    YifyMovies movie = YifyMovies();
    movie.data.movies = [];

    for (var json in decodedJson) {
      movie.data.movies.add(Movies.fromJson(json));
    }

    return movie;
  }
```

to

```
Future<YifyMovies> getData() async {
    var res = await http.get("https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json");
    var decodedJson = jsonDecode(res.body);

    YifyMovies movie = YifyMovies.fromJson(decodedJson);

    return movie;
  }
```

Comment: It removed the previous error. But now it's giving another error **typer 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'**.                                                               ```if (currentState is InHomeState) {
            YifyMovies yifyMovies = currentState.yifyMovies;
``` And using it for list view builder ```
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: yifyMovies.data.movies.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        Movies movies = yifyMovies.data.movies[i];```

Comment: That's an error from the parsing. Does the error point to a line in the YifyMovies class?

Comment: ```rating = json['rating'];``` I think if I removed this line this may get resolved but I need the rating too. So is there any way around?

Comment: You can change the type of rating from `double` to `num` so you can use both ints and doubles